# problem with QLocalSocket sending continues data to QLocalServer

Tags: qt, qlocalsocket, qlocalserver

I'm trying to send some data from QLocalSocket to QLocalSever in a loop. Sever only gets the first data and not receiving subsequent data, but if I introduce 1 mec delay between each call from the client then the server starts to receive everything. Please check out the below Client & Server code.

**client.cpp**

```
#include "client.h"
#include "QDataStream"
#include <QTest>

TestClient::TestClient() : m_socket{new QLocalSocket(this)}{
    m_socket->connectToServer("TestServer");
    if (m_socket->waitForConnected(1000)) {
      qDebug("socket Connected!");
    }
    connect(m_socket, &QLocalSocket::readyRead, this, &TestClient::onNewData);
}

void TestClient::onNewData() {
    qCritical() << "data received from server";
}

void TestClient::sendDataToServer() {
    QByteArray block;
    QDataStream out(&block, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    out.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_5_10);
    QString testString = "test data";
    out << quint32(testString.size());
    out << testString;
    m_socket->write(block);
    m_socket->flush();
}

void TestClient::startClient() {
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        //QTest::qWait(1); //works if I uncomment this line
        sendDataToServer();
    }
}
```

**server.cpp**

```
#include "server.h"

TestServer::TestServer() : m_server{new QLocalServer(this)} {
    QLocalServer::removeServer("TestServer");
    if (!m_server->listen("TestServer")) {
        qCritical() << "couldn't connect to server";
    }
    connect(m_server, &QLocalServer::newConnection, this, &TestServer::onNewConnection);
}

void TestServer::onNewConnection() {
    m_socket = m_server->nextPendingConnection();
    connect(m_socket, &QLocalSocket::readyRead, this,
            &TestServer::onNewData);
    connect(m_socket, &QLocalSocket::disconnected, m_socket,
            &QLocalSocket::deleteLater);
}

void TestServer::onNewData() {
    QLocalSocket* client = qobject_cast<QLocalSocket*>(sender());
    client->readAll();
    qCritical() << "data read by server";
}
```

from the qt doc, it's stated that

> readyRead() is not emitted recursively; if you reenter the event loop
> or call waitForReadyRead() inside a slot connected to the readyRead()
> signal, the signal will not be reemitted (although waitForReadyRead()
> may still return true).

so is this my problem? adding timer is the only solution here?

You can compile this test project -> http://www.filedropper.com/testsocket

Comment: Why do you think only the first chunk of data is being received by the server?  Note that the data connection is just a byte stream so multiple writes by the client don't necessarily correspond to multiple reads by the server

Comment: @G.M. Yes, I got the same answer in QT forum https://forum.qt.io/topic/120425/problem-with-qlocalsocket-sending-continues-data-to-qlocalserver . Shall I leave this question here or should I need to close it?